# The equality of Sobolev norm and Lebesgue norm, $\|v\|_{-2} = \|v\|_{L^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

We know that $L^2 \subset H^{-2}$ (where $H^{-2}$ is the dual space of $H^2_0$) so that  $\|v\|_{-2} \leq \|v\|_{L^2}$.

Could we show that:

If $v \in L^2$, then $v \in H^{-2}$ and

$$\|v\|_{-2} = \|v\|_{L^2}$$

Comment: No, this is not true. We similarly have $\|\nu\|_{L^2} \le \|\nu\|_{H^2}$, but not $\|\nu\|_{L^2} = \|\nu\|_{H^2}$.

Comment: Could we put any condition to have this equality? In other words: When we can achieve this equality $\|.\|_{-2} = \|.\|_{L_2}$.
For instance, we can prove that $\|u''\|_{H^{-2}} \leq \|u\|_{L^2}$, but could we achieve the other side of the inequality?.

Comment: No. If this equality would be true, $H^2_0$ would be a closed subspace of $L^2$. This would contradict the fact that $H^2_0$ is a proper, dense subspace of $L^2$.

Comment: But we know that $H_0^2$ is dense in $L^2$ in the zero norm. It is a closed subspace of $L^2$ in the 2-norm.

Comment: Yes, and equality would imply that it is dense and closed w.r.t. the zero norm. Further, the 2-norm is not defined on $L^2$, so it does not make sense to say "a closed subspace of $L^2$ in the $2$-norm".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these are very different norms. There is no more reason for $L^2$ norm to agree with the $H^{-2}$ than for it to agree with the $H^2$ norm. (Indeed, $H^{-2}$ norm is dual to $H^2$ while $L^2$ is dual to itself.) Considering that the $H^2$ norm is basically $\int |f''|^2$ (plus some lower order terms), it's like asking for what functions $\int |f|^2 = \int |f''|^2$.

The answer is: equality sometimes happens, but by chance and not for any interesting reason; the equality depends on how the norms are defined and how the underlying domain is scaled. It's a bit like for what subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ the area is equal to the perimeter.